# MDL on dynamic websites downgrading

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, material-design-lite

We have a old large ajax based GUI adapted to MDL.
The whole page content is build dynamically (from xml description).

```
componentHandler.downgradeElements( /all old notes/ ;
remove all old notes form DOM
add new page content to DOM
componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
```

This works fine, but it leaks memory if the component `MaterialLayout` is alos created dynamically .
With the ["downgrading fix (#2009"](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/pull/2009) the internal references are removed.
The reason for the memory leak is that the component `MaterialLayout` adds a listener to the MediaQueryList (MDL 1.1).

```
 this.screenSizeMediaQuery_.addListener(this.screenSizeHandler_.bind(this));
```

In MDL 1.1.2 there are two windows event handler added which lead to the same problem.

```
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (e) { ... } );
...
window.addEventListener('resize', windowResizeHandler);
```

This listeners are not removed  by `downgradeElements`.  And therefore the DOM elements are not GC.

Questions:

- Is it not indented to  delete the element with `MaterialLayout`?
- Is it completely wrong what I doing here?
- Is this an MDL issue?
- Is there a workaround without changing MDL code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a issue report for MDL [Layout downgrade #1340](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1340)

The final conclusion was:
*MDL is geared towards stateless sites with 1.x. Destroying the entire layout is not something that was thought about during the initial build of the layout component.*

So right answer is:
**It is not indented to delete the element with MaterialLayout for MDL 1.x.**

Additional information:
For a hack work around (for testing) I removed  adding the MediaQueryList listener from material.js (still 1.0.4 with deconstructComponentInternal form 1.1.2). This seems to work for our solution. I did not found any drawbacks (again in our solution) up to now.