# Unregister Material Disign Lite component in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, material-design-lite

I'm using MDL with Backbone.
How can i unregister components before removing view that contains any MDL component.

To register components i'm using `componentsHandler.upgradeDOM()` function from MDL. But without `componentsHandler.unregisterComponents()` appears memory leak.

I can't get MDL components that associated with current view to unregister them =(

Comment: Is there any documentation of the MDL API? I can't find anything that explains what those two methods actually *do*.

Comment: No, but u can read comments in JS file on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/master/src/mdlComponentHandler.js).

And some documentation in [Wiki](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/How-the-Component-Handler-works)

Comment: Have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/35940124/2115381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of this problem. I just add this code in remove method of all my Backbone views:

```
var components = this.el.querySelectorAll('[data-upgraded]'); 
if (components.length > 0) {
componentHandler.downgradeElements(components);
}
```

This code find all upgraded elements in view and downgrade them.